# fb_xd_fragment and FB.init

Tags: facebook, iframe

Our FB App page is being loaded multiple times on IE 6 and 7, with the &fb_xd_fragment parameter appended. This is only happen when the FBInit method is called.

I saw a lot of complains about this issue, but I couldn't understand how to eliminate the multiple calls, or why it only happen in IE.

I've tried the 'solution' proposed in [here](http://blog.colnect.com/2010/10/fbxdfragment-bug-workaround.html) but it didn't help - the page is being loaded several times.

I will appreciate any info on the subject.

Comment: We've the same issue, but it happens even without explicit `FB.init` call; we didn't have this call and had these problem.

According to http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=9777 , the workaround you're trying is the correct one.

Comment: Since the BugZilla bug tracker from FB will be discontinued, I've opened a new issue with them: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/127465724030553